# Proof of Serre duality for $D=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have been working through a proof of Serre duality, which proceeds by induction on the divisor $D$, but I am having trouble with the base-case. How can I prove that on a riemann surface X,  $H^0(X, \Omega) = H^1(X, \mathscr{O})^*$, where $\Omega$ is the sheaf of holomorphic 1-forms, $\mathscr{O}$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions. I know I have the linear map $H^0(X, \Omega) \times H^1(X, \mathscr{O}) \to H^1(X, \Omega) \to \mathbb{C}$, with the second arrow being the residue map. How do I show that this induces an isomorphism of the duals? I am hoping this is much simpler than the full proof of serre-duality, in which it is quite tedious to prove this induces an isomorphism.

Comment: You may find it helpful to look at Miranda's proof of Serre duality on Riemann surfaces in his book "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces". He doesn't take the same approach as you are proposing (that is, he doesn't reduce to the case $D = 0$), but instead shows that the residue map $H^0(X,\Omega(-D)) \to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}(D))^*$ is an isomorphism via a few (fairly explicit) calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explicit definition of the pairing in the case of the projective line. For $\mathcal{M}$ a coherent sheaf, an element of $H^1(\mathcal{M})$ represents an extension$$0 \to \mathcal{M} \to \text{?} \to \mathcal{O} \to 0.$$If we are given a homomorphism $\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{O}(-2)$, this induces an extension$$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-2) \to \text{?} \to \mathcal{O} \to 0.$$Now, there is one sort of universal such extension with $\text{?} = \mathcal{O}(-1) + \mathcal{O}(-1)$, and any such extension is a scalar multiple of the universal one, so we get a scalar at the end. This defines the pairing.

Understanding the universal extension is key. One way of defining it via the principal parts sequence for $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and then twisted by $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. It also relates closely to the extension connecting the tangent bundle of affine space with that of projective space, which is really where all this comes from most explicitly.